# Validation of a result (logic)

Tags: real-analysis, logic, proof-writing

Suppose that the nonnegative function $f$ is such that **for any** $v>1$ there are $C,L>0$ so that $f(x)\leq Cx^{-v}$ for all $x>L$. It is clear that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Is it true that $f(x)x^l\to 0$ for all $l\in\mathbb N$?

**Comments**

Let $l>2$ be fixed. On one hand, there exists $v>l$ such that $f(x)x^l\leq Cx^{l-v}\to 0, x\to\infty,$ by hypothesis.
On the other hand, there exists $v\leq l$ such that $f(x)x^l\leq Cx^{l-v}\to \infty, x\to\infty.$

What conclusion can I make?

My intuition reads the "for any $v>1$" part as "$v$ can be chosen arbitrarily large". In this sense, $f(x)x^l\to 0$ follows. My conflict is that there are values of $v$ such that I get $f(x)x^l\leq \infty$ which does not prove what I want. What is the right idea: "$v$ can be chosen arbitrarily large" vs "the result should follow for all $v>1$"?

**Example**

Let $l\in\mathbb N^*$ be fixed. Consider the following hypotheses:

1. $f>0$ is such that there is $v>l$,  $f(x)\leq Cx^{-v}$.
2. $f>0$ is such that for all $v>1$,  $f(x)\leq Cx^{-v}$.

Under 1, $f(x)x^l\to 0$. As 2 implies 1, the same conclusion must hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For given $l \in \Bbb N$ you want to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)x^l=0$. To this end, you use the given hypothesis with “a suitable” $v$ such that the desired conclusion follows.

As you noticed, any $v > l$ works. So you can argue as follows:

> For $v = l+1$ there exist $C, L  > 0$ such that  $f(x)\leq Cx^{-l-1}$ for $x > L$. Then
> $$
>  0 \le f(x)x^l \le \frac{C}{x}
> $$
> for $x > L$, which implies $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)x^l=0$.

That is a complete proof. It does not matter that other choices of $v$ do not imply the desired conclusion.

Comment: If $f$ satisfies the upper bound  for $v>1$, then $f$ satisfies it for $v>l$. That is the requirement that the upper bound is valid for all $v>1$ is stronger than necessary for the convergence of $f(x)x^l$. Is this idea correct? It seems a basic logic problem, but I'm struggled on it.

Comment: @CelineHarumi: Not really. If the  requirement is satisfied for some $v$ then it is automatically satisfied for all smaller $v'$. Therefore it makes to difference if you require it for all $v > 1$ or for all $v > 10000$.

Comment: Hm, this is the key observation. Thanks